# Finding possible combinations of 1 and 2 with a constant sum

Tags: c, algorithm, combinations

This is a task to be done in C.  Can you tell me how to approach this?

A train has a length of *n* meters.  It is made up of individual compartments of 1 or 2 meters in length.  How many different combinations of such compartments exist for a train of a given length?  Write a function `Train (n)` that computes this.

Comment: Isn't this a school assignment by any chance?

Comment: to be done in "C language" so why is a Java tag?

Comment: If it's to be done in c, the 'java' tag is a bit out-of-place. If it's homework, concider adding 'homework' to you tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the simplest cases and look for regularities.

1. `Train (1)` is obviously 1: (1).
2. `Train (2)` is obviously 2: (1 1) and (2).
3. `Train (3)` is 3: (1 1 1), (1 2), and (2 1).  The first two can be combined into conjoining (1) with (1 1) resp (2).  The latter are exactly the combinations of `Train (2)`.  So, `Train (3)` is `Train (2) + 1`.
4. `Train (4)` is 5: (1 1 1 1) (1 1 2) (1 2 1) (2 1 1) (2 2).  Again, we can combine the first as (1) with (1 1 1), (1 2), and (2 1), which are the combinations of `Train (3)`.  The last are (2) conjoined with (1 1) and (2), which are the combinations of `Train (2)`.  So, `Train (4)` is `Train (3) + Train (2)`.  Now, looking back at `Train (3)`, we see that the `+ 1` is `Train (1)`.

Now it seems clear that `Train (n)` is always `Train (n - 1) + Train (n - 2)`.  That is exactly the definition of the Fibonacci sequence.

Now, let us see how that is translated to C.

1. The function skeleton:  `Train` takes one integer argument and returns an integer:

   ```
   int Train (int n) {
   }
   ```
2. The definition we worked out:

   ```
   int Train (int n) {
       return Train (n - 1) + Train (n - 2);
   }
   ```
3. This will recurse infinitely, so we need to stop it at the base case.  One base case is clear: `Train (1)` is 1:

   ```
   int Train (int n) {
       if (n == 1) {
           return 1;
       } else {
           return Train (n - 1) + Train (n - 2);
       }
   }
   ```
4. This is still not enough.  Imagine what `Train (2)` does: it will calculate `Train (1) + Train (0)`.  `Train (1)` is no problem, but `Train (0)` will calculate `Train (-1) + Train (-2)`, which again recurses infinitely.  So, we need another base case: `Train (2)` is 2.

   ```
   int Train (int n) {
       if (n == 1) {
           return 1;
       } else if (n == 2) {
           return 2;
       } else {
           return Train (n - 1) + Train (n - 2);
       }
   }
   ```
5. This works, but we can simplify the base cases:

   ```
   int Train (int n) {
       if (n < 3) {
           return n;
       } else {
           return Train (n - 1) + Train (n - 2);
       }
   }
   ```
6. If you now just paste that last code snippet into your homework without working through the "too long, didn't read" preliminaries, I have successfully undermined your education, and you will never learn to program.  You are welcome.
7. This is not the best way to calculate Fibonacci numbers.  Why?  How should you modify the code to avoid duplication of effort?  Are there different approaches imaginable?  Which ones?

Comment: Thnks Very Much Dude.,Really nice END comment by U.

Answer (score 0):

That's a simple [fibonacci sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number).
For any train of length `n` first cart can be of length 1 or 2. That brings us to `f(n) = f(n - 1) + f(n - 2)` formula.

I probably don't have to tell you how to calculate fibonacci numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this recursive formula answers the question 
if (n <= 2) return n 
Train(n) = Train(n-1) + Train(n-2)

Comment: Thnks Very Much Dude. for ur kind help